# $ A = \left\{ (0,0),(1,0) \right\} $ is not connected space in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology

How prove that $ A = \left\{ (0,0),(1,0) \right\} $ is not connected space in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with euclidean metric?

I know that $A$ is not connected iff exsists non-empty subset $A$ which is closed and open.

So I'm relly confused because I have only two subsets of $A$: $\left\{ (0,0) \right\}$ and $\left\{(1,0) \right\}$ but both of them aren't open (they are only closed sets). So $A$ is connected?

Comment: Those sets are also open as subsets of $A$ (ie. in the subspace topology)

Comment: Each singleton is open (in $A$).

Comment: But in $\mathbb{R}^2$ each singleton (set $\left\{ (x,y) \right\}$) is not open, yes?

Comment: In $A$ each of these singletons is open because it is the complement of a closed set (the other singleton).

Answer (score 1):

The topology on $A$ is given by (using the open sets inherited from the subspace topology), $$\tau=\{\emptyset, \{(0,0)\},\{(1,0)\}, A\}.$$

In particular, $A=\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(1,0)\}$ and so $A$ can be written as the dijoint union of two open subset of itself. It follows that $A$ is not connected.